# How to hide secret information with .bash_profile

Tags: python, password

I have come across a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5iWhQWVXosU) where for best practice one should put their login credentials in **.bash_profile**. However I can't seem to find this on the Raspberry Pi.

And to retrieve this information one should:

```
import os

USER = os.environ.get('USER_DETAILS')
PSWD = os.environ.get('PSWD_DETAILS')
```

**QUESTION:**

Which file do I have edit to pass on my email/sql/etc. credentials so I can later call them from with the `os.environ.get()` *ie* `os.environ.get("SQL_USER")`?

Comment: Anyone who uses a video to "explain" how to configure a text file must be immediately suspect. You can't find it because it generally doesn't exist, and it is unclear what exactly you are trying to "hide" or from whom

Comment: @Milliways suspect what? I'm trying to learn best practice... Is this not best practice?

Comment: We obvious have a semantic dissonance - my usage of the word is not a verb.

Comment: @Milliways perhaps, if you had _obviously_ used correct grammar, one would not have any semantic dissonance

Comment: Best practice is to explain the question and not to refer to external sources to understand the question: [What's wrong with “I followed this tutorial” kind of questions?](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/whats-wrong-with-i-followed-this-tutorial-kind-of-questions)

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what the video you reference says, but Raspbian configures the login shell using `~/.profile`

You can include extra environment variables in this file.
NOTE this won't "hide" anything as it is readable by all users.

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

export MAILTO=""
```